# Finding n mutually perpendicular vectors in n-dimensional space.

Tags: geometry, orthogonality, dimensional-analysis

Is there a way to find n mutually perpendicular vectors in a n-dimensional space, where coefficient of each direction is either 1 or -1?

For example, when n = 2, a possible solution could be:
`A = (1, -1), B = (1, 1)`

Similarly, when n = 4, a possible solution could be: `A = (-1, 1, 1, 1), B =  (1, -1, 1, 1), C = (1, 1, -1, 1), D = (1, 1, 1, -1)`

Is there some way to calculate a solution for higher values of n?

Comment: Obviously $n$ must be even

Comment: Yes, It must be even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$ vectors you are looking for form what is called a [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). See that article for various ways to construct Hadamard matrices and a discussion of what is known about the existence of Hadamard matrices.